# Xamarin.Forms with Prism 8 RegionManager KeyNotFoundException

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, prism

I'm having an issue migrating from Prism's partialview support to using Regions. The problem occurs in the sample below. I have the same issue in other projects with Prism.Forms 8 + Xamarin.Forms 5.

https://github.com/CrossGeeks/PrismRegionsXFSample

```
System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: The region manager does not contain the ContentRegion region.
  at Prism.Regions.RegionCollection.get_Item (System.String regionName) [0x0000f] in /_/src/Forms/Prism.Forms.Regions/Regions/RegionCollection.cs:43 
  at Prism.Regions.RegionManager.RequestNavigate (System.String regionName, System.Uri target, System.Action`1[T] navigationCallback, Prism.Navigation.INavigationParameters navigationParameters) [0x00013] in /_/src/Forms/Prism.Forms.Regions/Regions/RegionManager.cs:44 
  at Prism.Regions.RegionManager.RequestNavigate (System.String regionName, System.Uri target, System.Action`1[T] navigationCallback) [0x00000] in /_/src/Forms/Prism.Forms.Regions/Regions/RegionManager.cs:37 
  at Prism.Regions.IRegionManagerExtensions.RequestNavigate (Prism.Regions.IRegionManager regionManager, System.String regionName, System.String target, System.Action`1[T] navigationCallback) [0x00024] in /_/src/Forms/Prism.Forms.Regions/Regions/IRegionManagerExtensions.cs:40 
  at RegionInitialize.ViewModels.MainPageViewModel.Test () [0x00001] in /Users/lestersconyers/Downloads/RegionInitialize/RegionInitialize/RegionInitialize/ViewModels/MainPageViewModel.cs:39 
  at Prism.Commands.DelegateCommand.Execute () [0x00000] in /_/src/Prism.Core/Commands/DelegateCommand.cs:49 
  at Prism.Commands.DelegateCommand.Execute (System.Object parameter) [0x00000] in /_/src/Prism.Core/Commands/DelegateCommand.cs:67 
  at Prism.Commands.DelegateCommandBase.System.Windows.Input.ICommand.Execute (System.Object parameter) [0x00000] in /_/src/Prism.Core/Commands/DelegateCommandBase.cs:62 
  at Xamarin.Forms.ButtonElement.ElementClicked (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement visualElement, Xamarin.Forms.Internals.IButtonElement ButtonElementManager) [0x00008] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\ButtonElement.cs:60 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Button.SendClicked () [0x00000] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\Button.cs:173 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.ButtonElementManager.OnButtonTouchUpInside (Xamarin.Forms.IButtonController element) [0x00009] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS\Renderers\ButtonElementManager.cs:86 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.ButtonRenderer.OnButtonTouchUpInside (System.Object sender, System.EventArgs eventArgs) [0x00000] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS\Renderers\ButtonRenderer.cs:189 
  at UIKit.UIControlEventProxy.Activated () [0x00004] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/14.8.0.3/src/Xamarin.iOS/UIKit/UIControl.cs:38 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

  at (wrapper managed-to-native) UIKit.UIApplication.UIApplicationMain(int,string[],intptr,intptr)
  at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.IntPtr principal, System.IntPtr delegate) [0x00005] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/14.8.0.3/src/Xamarin.iOS/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:86 
  at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.String principalClassName, System.String delegateClassName) [0x0000e] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/14.8.0.3/src/Xamarin.iOS/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:65 
  at RegionInitialize.iOS.Application.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00001] in /Users/lestersconyers/Downloads/RegionInitialize/RegionInitialize/RegionInitialize.iOS/Main.cs:17
```

Comment: Hi, I download the sample and run it without problems, if you just run the sample directly can you met the problems? Because from your log that's a little different from me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I download the sample and run it without problems, if you just run the sample directly can you met the problems? Because from your log that's a little different from me.

This is
`yours:/Users/lestersconyers/Downloads/RegionInitialize/RegionInitialize/RegionInitialize.iOS/Main.cs:17`
This is `mine:D:\MyTestPlace\xamarin\PrismRegionsXFSample\RegionPrismSample.iOS\Main.cs`

It seems a little different.

And from the log the problem occurred in this line:
at RegionInitialize.ViewModels.MainPageViewModel.Test () [0x00001] in /Users/lestersconyers/Downloads/RegionInitialize/RegionInitialize/RegionInitialize/ViewModels/MainPageViewModel.cs:39
while others was framework related. And in the sample which I download, I have no line 39 in MainPageViewModel.cs

So I think maybe that's some problems within Initialize function in your MainPageViewModel.cs file.

Comment: Sorry, I posted the stacktrace from the wrong project. But I've isolated this issue. It does run straightaway in Visual Studio for Mac. But it bombs when developing with Rider. I will ship this over to the Rider team. Thank you.

Comment: It actually _does_ work with Rider if you start without debugging. I've submitted a bug to the Rider team.

Comment: I was going crazy trying to figure this out myself.  Why wasn't regions working on my Android emulator with this very same sample project.  I was even going to see how I could register the region to the regionManager programmatically.  Maybe that would help?  Then I find out that this is a Rider issue! OMG!  Thank you for keeping my sanity.